# EDMX Reference in other project : type used in a using statment must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, using

[image]

[image]

Hi All,

I want to have a single project which holds the DataSchema files like EDMX files.

The problem which i am facing is if i create a reference of the PRJDataSchema Project
project and try to query the EmployeeEntity i get a "type used in a using statment must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'"

How can i resolve this problem.

If i create a class file in PRJDataSchema , like i have created a Test.cs file then i get
no problem.

I want to fix the problem in screenshot 1.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a reference to the `System.Data.Entity` library in the `PRJDataAccess` project, it is necessary, because your context refers to the assembly.

Comment: Thanks had to manually add reference of "System.Data.Entity" to PRJDataAccess and then add it as using System.Data.Entity to the EmployeeDAL.cs and that solved the issue. Stupid me :|